# How can I include more than one string/link so that I can have multiple texts with a link?

Tags: java, android, xml, string

I am currently doing a beginner level app on android for my school project. I've already done most of it but cannot manage to include 3 texts wherein through a string/link they send you a website discussing a certain subject matter. I have managed to do one that works:

```
string name="app_name"TextView/string
string name="link"a href="https://fpformacionprofesional.com/fp-grado-superior-3/pro-ALAVA/"ARABA/a/string
string name="araba"ARABA/string
```

But I want to include another two provinces in the North of Spain but everytime I try to create a new string it doesn't work and takes the other string/link name and link. I have tried to change the string name to 1 and 2 and still doesnt work and have also created another code in Java to refer to the new textview I have created.

The project is due tomorrow and I just cannot find any tutorial or online forum where they solve this problem. Hope you can help.

Comment: Rather than using TextView, use WebView for HTML links.

Comment: Please can you resubmit your XML file as the formatting has got lost somewhere. Please also post some code to show what you have tried to do.